# How to using k8s Job extract a file inside a dedicated docker image and load it into a k8s secret

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift

I am trying to extract a license file which is inside docker image, and convert this license into a k8s secret by using a Job.

Here are some mandatory requirements:

1. This docker image, which contains the license file, does not have any base image or binary, it does not have entry point as well. It is a blank image only store the file. Because I would like to avoid any security issue.
2. We have a dedicated image, which contains `kubectl` binary, to be used as the container image for running this k8s Job. But it does not have `podman` or `docker`, so we could not pull image containing license file in job runtime.

Blocker: How to load this image with License file into a k8s Job, and the Job pod could reads the License file, and convert it into a Secret.

My initial idea was

1. Leveraging k8s mechanism pulling the image with License file when k8s Job is created,
2. Share this License file from the image with k8s Job pod, using volume mounts
3. K8s Job pod runtime reads this License file, and convert it to Secret

But I have not able to successfully load the image, because the image does not have entry point.

Any help and idea is appreciated!

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far? What is the image with the license file? Do you have any control over that image?

Comment: You really seem to be trying to do something unnatural with that first docker image. Why can't you just put it in a secret or configmap from the beginning?